# Hill cipher encryption and decryption in python

Tags: python

I doubt the encryption have any issue but when I encrypt and decrypt I should receive the original message but yet I'm receiving a whole new text. I cant seem to find the error. I'm new to hill cipher.

```py
import numpy as np

def encrypt(message, key):
    message = message.upper()
    key = key.upper()

    key_matrix = np.array([list(map(lambda x: ord(x) % 65, key[i:i+3])) for i in range(0, len(key), 3)])
    message += 'X' * (3 - len(message) % 3) if len(message) % 3 != 0 else ''

    cipher_text = ''
    for i in range(0, len(message), 3):
        message_vector = np.array(list(map(lambda x: ord(x) % 65, message[i:i+3])))
        cipher_vector = np.dot(message_vector, key_matrix.T) % 26
        cipher_text += ''.join(chr(c + 65) for c in cipher_vector)

    print("Ciphertext:", cipher_text)
    return cipher_text

def modinv(a, m):
    # Extended Euclidean Algorithm
    m0, x0, x1 = m, 0, 1
    while a > 1:
        q = a // m
        m, a = a % m, m
        x0, x1 = x1 - q * x0, x0
    return x1 + m0 if x1 < 0 else x1

def decrypt(cipher_text, key):
    cipher_text = cipher_text.upper()
    key = key.upper()

    key_matrix = np.array([list(map(lambda x: ord(x) % 65, key[i:i+3])) for i in range(0, len(key), 3)])
    key_matrix_inv = np.linalg.inv(key_matrix) % 26

    plain_text = ''
    for i in range(0, len(cipher_text), 3):
        cipher_vector = np.array(list(map(lambda x: ord(x) % 65, cipher_text[i:i+3])))
        plain_vector = np.dot(cipher_vector, key_matrix_inv) % 26
        plain_text += ''.join(chr(int(c) % 26 + 65) for c in plain_vector)

    print("Decrypted Text:", plain_text)
    return plain_text

# Driver Code
def main():
    message = "GFG"
    key = "GYBNQKURP"

    cipher_text = encrypt(message, key)

    # Use the same key for decryption
    decrypted_text = decrypt(cipher_text, key)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

output:

```
Ciphertext: GKJ
Decrypted Text: ZEX
```